# Issues determining velocity in a totally elastic collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity, collision

A block of mass $M_1$ is attached by string to a support. The block is raised to a height and released. It then strikes a block of mass $M_2$ on a frictionless surface. Find the velocity of block $M_2$, assuming a totally elastic collision. 
[image: block m_1 on string raised to height h]

I have calculated the velocity ($v_1$) of $M_1$:

KE=PE

.5$M_1$$v_1^2$=$M_1$gh

 $v_1$=$\sqrt(2gh)$ 


From there I try to calculate the velocity ($v'_2$) of $M_2$:

I use the conservation of momentum to solve for $v'_2$

$M_1$$v_1$+$M_2$$v_2$=$M_1$$v'_1$+$M_2$$v'_2$

and I assume that $v_1$ = $\sqrt(2gh)$ 

 $v_2$ = 0 

 $v'_1$ = 0 (can I assume this since I am not sure of the actual masses?)

and then solve for $v'_2$ 

Doing this I get $v'_2 = \frac{M_1}{M_2}\sqrt(2gh)$ , yet the answer given is 

 $v'_2 = \frac{2M_1}{M_1+M_2}\sqrt(2gh)$

If I don't assume $v'_1$ = 0 , then I get

$v'_2 = \frac{M_1}{M_2}(\sqrt(2gh)-v'_1)$

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? I think there is something fundamentally that I am missing. Thanks for your time!

Comment: What does it mean "elastic"? How does you answer change if the collision isn't elastic?

Comment: Inelastic collisions involve both masses moving as a singular mass with a singular velocity after collision.            
$M_1$$v_1$+$M_2$$v_2$=($M_1$+$M_2$)$v_3$

Comment: In an elastic collision, $KE = KE'$.  No energy is lost in the collision.  Since the masses are not stated to be equal, you must assume them different, so $v_1'$ cannot be assumed to be 0.